# Parameter does not exist as a stored procedure parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectCompletionNonCompletionCourseReport]              
  @LearnerName   NVARCHAR(510) = NULL,              
  @ManagerId     INT = NULL,              
  @CourseId      INT = NULL,              
  @StartDateFrom SMALLDATETIME = NULL,              
  @StartDateTo   SMALLDATETIME = NULL,              
  @TeamList      XML = NULL,              
  @JobID         NVARCHAR(max)=NULL,              
  @CourseStatus  NVARCHAR(20)=NULL,      
  @ReportAdminID INT=0,      
  @ReportTeamList   NVARCHAR(max)=NULL,
  @RowsTotal int  = 0,
  @PageIndex int = 1,
  @RowsPerPage int = 10      
AS              
BEGIN              

  DECLARE @TblCrieiria TABLE              
    (              
       id         INT IDENTITY(1, 1),              
       areacode   NVARCHAR(11),              
       regioncode NVARCHAR(11),              
       teamcode   NVARCHAR(11)              
    )              
    IF @TeamList IS NULL              
    BEGIN              
    INSERT INTO @TblCrieiria VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL)              
    END              

   BEGIN
```

This is the beginning of the procedure...

```
using (Database db = new Database(DScape.DAL.Config.ConfignPropertyName.DSCAPELMS_CONNECTION_STRING_NAME))
{
            var cmd = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandText = "SelectCompletionNonCompletionCourseReport",
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LearnerName", LearnerName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ManagerId", ManagerId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseId", CourseId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateFrom", StartDateFrom);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTo", StartDateTo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamList", TeamList);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobID", JobID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseStatus", CourseStatus);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportAdminID", ReportAdminID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportTeamList", ReportTeamList);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", 1);

                DataSet dsClient = db.GetDataSet(cmd);
                if (dsClient.Tables.Count > 0)
                    return dsClient.Tables[0];
                else
                    return null;
        }
```

This is the method which communicates with the procedure, and it gaves me an error

> Parameter does not exist as a stored procedure parameter/ function/procedure take too many arguments...

It's about `@PageIndex` parameter. Doesn't matter what is the value, we don't talk for values here but for parameter which is defined in the stored procedure but doesn't work?

And for the record, this problem did pop-up today w/o any code writing/modifying just appeared as I tried to do that report, when yesterday it was all good...I have a teammate which is next to me with absolute the same code both in sql and c# and it works just fine on his pc, but mine throws this errors, I'm trying to resolve this from 3 hours and I am completely out of answers , so please give me direction in which should I continue to resolve this .....................

and I say again, the problem is not from the connection to DB or type of the parameter or the value, the error is committed with the parameter itself - does not exist in the procedure, which is insane in my opinion.

Comment: You're not defining any values for `@RowsTotal` and `@RowsPerPage` in your C# code ....

Comment: FREEFALLER - No, there is no call on another sproc within this one.

Comment: marc_s -- Okey, I will add them aswell, but as I said, absolute the same code is running fine just next to me ...

Comment: Are you sure your app is connecting to the exact same copy of the database? If any of your connection strings has the options `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName`, it's a good chance they're not pointing at the same copy you think they are.

Comment: marc_s it's the same. bla blabla Sproc takes too many arguments (PageIndex ;) )

Comment: I think you try run script(create stored procedure) and try run code. It`s maybe because you pass wrong name of parameter. 99%

Comment: Guys,I told you already twice I have absolute the same code running on other machine just fine, I tried to connect to local DB, server DB, and other server DB which are 3 different back ups of DB and none of them worked so far. It's some kind of computer issue, but I have absolutely no idea where and what should I look for... this is the direction U can help me, I don't need code suggestions, the code is just fine since its working but not on this pc and not today, why ? What can break that fAking procedure so it wont take this PageIndex as Faking value I'm really confused,pissed and hopeless

Comment: Attach SQL Profiler to the database you think you are working with and see if its actually calling the expected database. If it is, you will get the SQL statements and be able to trace which one is the offending one.

Comment: Can you post the *exact* error message please?  Use copy and paste if you can.

Comment: @PageIndex is not a parameter for procedure SelectCompletionNonCompletionCourseReport.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

This error occurs if I place 9 parameters and PageIndex is the last one.

////This error occurs nomatter if I place all of the parameters or just 11, including one of these - PageIndex, RowsTotal, RowsPerPage
SEE THE COMMENT BELOW

Comment: Procedure or function SelectCompletionNonCompletionCourseReport has too many arguments specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: StingyJack - THANK YOU ! That profiler did perfect job! :)

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: I didn't solve it yet, but I found out that the reason this occurs is not about something irregular in procedures or code file. My webconfig file is set up to communicate with local BD, but somehow,someone changed something and it actually does not operate with it but with that one which is on our second server, and there they also did changes to the procedures(Simple comment on the last 3 parameters) and now I am dealing with the question how to properly connect VS to the exact DB I want. I don't have much experience in this area but I do feel like a total idiot after all this efforts ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that all parameters are optional, you are not required to explicitly provide *any* of them from your client code. Default values will be provided for you by SQL Server. The contract explictly states it in the stored procedure's signature.

An optional parameter is exactly that: optional. If you had provided the incorrect number of parameters, SQL Server would have returned a different error, indicating that the number of parameters was incorrect. This is not the case. Instead, you are seeing that you are asking for a parameter that is *undefined,* which indicates that the stored procedure signature you *think* you are calling does not match the stored procedure signature you are *actually* calling.

Verify that you are *both* connecting to the same database instance. If you are not, verify that the stored procedure is *identical* on both database instances.

Comment: Everything is verified, If I comment {cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", 1);} it returns me all the rows on one page, but since there might be reports with 15k rows I need pageIndex. I don't know what information can I give you in addition so you could have a bit larger perspective on this problem ;/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you provide @RowsCount as a parameter, with a value of zero?

Comment: I tried to add all of the params - 13 it gave me this error :
Procedure or function SelectCompletionNonCompletionCourseReport has too many arguments specified.
After that I tried with each of the last 3 params individually, also got this error.
When I commented the row it "@ReportListTeams" and added the PageIndex after it in adding params phase it said that @PageIndex is not a parameter of this procedure.

Comment: I do not have any other procedure with that name or even close to it. I checked parameters with schema_parameters, also with sql profiler

Answer (score 0):

parameter count doesnt match. check the params again.

You have to send parameters for rowstotal and rowsperpage as well because you have declared them at the top before "begin" clause.

If you do not want to send that params and they will be just constant, please declare them below as variable or constant, not a parameter.

i.e.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteById
@TableName sysname, 
@Id int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @StrId AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @StrId = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Id)

--any sp code here
END
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But all parameters are optional; I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Its not a problem ;) Thats the way it should be done, but for this particular error It does not help.